# Add remove field in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to  add and remove some html input in JavaScript.
I have done some code for the add function and it work properly, but I'm unable to remove. My code is following:

```
fields = 1;
function addInput() { 
  if (fields != 10) {
      document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += "<tr><td width='15%' align='left' valign='top' class='subheading'><input type='text' name='date[]' id='date[]' /></td><td width='15%' align='left' valign='top' class='subheading'><input type='text' name='time[]' id='time[]' /></td><td width='20%' align='left' valign='top' class='subheading'><input type='text' name='module[]' id='module[]' /></td><td width='15%' align='left' valign='top' class='subheading'><input type='text' name='organisation[]' id='organisation[]' /></td><td width='20%' align='left' valign='top' class='subheading' nowrap='nowrap'><input type='text' name='category[]' id='category[]' /></td><td width='20%' align='left' valign='top' class='text' nowrap='nowrap'>Add | Remove </td></tr>";
      fields += 1;
   } else {
       document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += "<br />Only 10 upload fields allowed.";
       document.form.add.disabled=true;
  }
}
fields1=10
function removeInput() { 
   if (fields1 !=1) {
       document.getElementById('text').innerHTML += "";
       fields -= 1;
       }
}
```

and my PHP function is:

```
function addSession()
       {?>
       <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
         <tr>
         <td width="10%" align="left" valign="top" colspan="6" bgcolor="#993333" class="heading">Add Session  </span></td>

         </tr><tr  class="bgrow">
         <td width="10%" align="left" valign="top" class="subheading">Datum </span></td>
         <td width="20%" align="left" valign="top" class="subheading">Tijd</td>
         <td width="35%" align="left" valign="top" class="subheading">Module</td>
         <td width="15%" align="left" valign="top" class="subheading">Organisatie</td>
         <td width="20%" align="left" valign="top" class="subheading" nowrap="nowrap">Category</td>
         <td width="20%" align="left" valign="top" class="subheading" nowrap="nowrap">Action</td>
         </tr>
         <tr  > 
         <td width="15%" align="left" valign="top" class="subheading"><input type="text" name="date_0" id="date_0" /></td>
         <td width="15%" align="left" valign="top" class="subheading"><input type="text" name="time_0" id="time_0" /></td>
         <td width="20%" align="left" valign="top" class="subheading"><input type="text" name="module_0" id="module_0" /></td>
         <td width="15%" align="left" valign="top" class="subheading"><input type="text" name="organisation_o" id="organisation_o" /></td>
         <td width="20%" align="left" valign="top" class="subheading" nowrap="nowrap"><input type="text" name="cat_0" id="cat_0" /></td>
         <td width="20%" align="left" valign="top" class="text" nowrap="nowrap"><span onclick="addInput()" class="link">Add</span> | <span onclick="removeInput()" class="link">Remove </span></td>
         </tr>
         <tbody id="text">
         </tbody>

       <?php
           }

            ?>
```

Can anyone give me a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var fields1 = 10;
function removeInput() 
{ 

    if (fields1 !=1)
    {
        var someInput = document.getElementById('text');
        someInput.parentNode.removeChild(someInput.childNodes[0]);
        fields1 -= 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: if it worked for you, please accept the answer ;) you have to click on the check that turns green.